# How to avoid adding element in Spring JdbcTemplate batchUpdate method when using ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I need to skip particular element from the list i.e. objectlistToprocess while having batch update using Spring jdbcTemplate.

1. **one way is to remove elements from List prior calling batch update
   and provide list. But this will have more iteration over list, one over whole list to remove elements then over batch update to set values.**
2. **avoid iterations and simply skip element in batchupdate method (but how).**

```java
this.getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(Query,objectlistToprocess ,batchSize, new 
     ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter<MyObject>() {
            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, MyObject) throws SQLException {
               // set all parameterized values
               // SKIP ELEMENT BUT HOW?????
            }
     }
```

Comment: Use 1. It has almost 0 chance of having any significant performance impact. Or don't add the element to the list in the first place.

Comment: @JBNizet i have almost 20+ lists with variant sizes that can go from 10-50 in each list. and i have to first remove specfic elements from 20+ list, so my point is to remove those in BatchUpdate and avoid pre removal using FOR loop. For us even 1 sec delay over removing list items is BIG performance issue. as we need to process huge data.

Comment: OK, so let's assume the worst case and say that you have 50 elements in each of your 20 lists. 20 * 50 == 1000. That's not huge. That's tiny. Java doesn't need 1 second to filter 1000 elements. It needs a few nanoseconds or microseconds. And the time it takes compared to the time needed to populate the statement, send the data over the network to the database, wait for it to write the data on the disk and get back the result is completely negligible.

Comment: Not to mention that you would have to execute the filtering logic on each element anyway if you put it inside the call to setValues().

Comment: I do agree that its negligible but to have good logic and minimize overheads. we should adopt that programming approach. BTW number are for just one profile i have 100K profiles to process which contains that list. BUT how to implement that skip logic on setValues or batch update.?